# Python KeyError Exception

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-mining

I am facing problem in this section showing KeyError: 'BrandName' [Here is the screenshot of my below program output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjKK6.jpg) please help me to solve this error.

```
top_10_brands = top_10_brands.reset_index()
tt_brand = top_10_brands['BrandName']
tt_brand2 = tt_brand.reset_index()
top_10_brand_list = list(set(tt_brand2['BrandName']))
top_10_brand_list.remove('All')
```

Comment: Can you show what your `top_10_brands` dataframe looks like?

Comment: Can you put the traceback in the question rather than a link to an image?

Comment: That link shows a `ValueError`. It also explains exactly what's going wrong. You need to either change the index name or the column before you `reset_index` that way there isn't a collision between similarly named columns.

Comment: ['Apple',
 'HTC',
 'BlackBerry',
 'BLU',
 'Samsung',
 'Motorola',
 'CNPGD',
 'LG',
 'Nokia',
 'OtterBox']